# Function Overloading for 'high/'low

Tags: vhdl

Many of my VHDL designs rely on "for ___ generate" loops where I use the `generate` to instantiate a component with generics. More often or not the width of the ports of these components are dependent on the generics passed to them in the generate loop.

In these component blocks, I often have to use the attributes in signal assignments and logic (e.g. `my_sig'high` and `my_sig'low`). This means that if my signal name is very long this technique becomes very cumbersome.

Has anyone done any function overloading on the `'` "operator"? (NB I know it's not an operator I just can't remember what the technical term for this is)

Let's say I have the following code for a shift register...

```
signal my_shift_reg : std_logic_vector(my_generic_high_number downto my_generic_low_number);

...

my_shift_reg(my_shift_reg'high downto my_shift_reg'low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(my_shift_reg'hig -1 downto my_shift_reg'low);
```

As you can hopefully see, that is quite cumbersome to write and would be even more complicated if I had to have some logic to calculate what bits of `my_shift_reg` to take out.

This could be made simpler by having an overloading function on the `'high` and `'low` (I know they're not functions just stay with me...) to know that they're equivalent to `my_shift_reg'high` and `my_shift_reg'low`. Thus the assignment operation could be re-written as...

```
my_shift_reg('high downto 'low + 1) <= my_shift_reg('high -1 downto 'low);
```

If this could be done that would be amazing! And a potentially nice QOL thing for future VHDL updates.

Comment: The name you're looking for is attribute. attributes 'high and 'low are built into the language. They are not functions but in theory you could override them, but they probably wouldnt work like you'd expect or want as you would have to re-define high and low for every object, and would end up being far more work than you're wanting.

Comment: VHDL is a formal notation. The predefined attribute of an array `'high` is a function that returns a value from an implementation dependent simulation kernel structure describing  the attribute name's prefix and has no history nor could without a prefix. User defined attributes are constants of an arbitrary type associated with named entities, whose names also can't  contain an apostrophe. Speculative questions solicit opinions, instead ask questions about actual programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

The `alias` statement might help, eg

```
alias m is my_shift_reg;

my_shift_reg(m'high downto m'low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(m'high -1 downto m'low);
```

This is less typing, but perhaps harder to understand. This is a bit more typing, but perhaps easier to understand:

```
alias index is my_shift_reg;

my_shift_reg(index'high downto index'low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(index'high -1 downto index'low);
```

Here's a variation which might be easier to understand:

```
alias high is my_generic_high_number;
alias low is my_generic_low_number;

my_shift_reg(high downto low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(high -1 downto low);
```

You can put the alias declaration inside the process so that it is only in scope within that process so (a) the alias names can be reused and (b) the alias declarations are nearer to where they are used, which might help readability. eg:

```
  process (clock) is
    alias index is my_shift_reg;
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      my_shift_reg(index'high downto index'low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(index'high -1 downto index'low);
    end if;
  end process;
```

or

```
  process (clock) is
    alias high is my_generic_high_number;
    alias low is my_generic_low_number;
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      my_shift_reg(high downto low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(high -1 downto low);
    end if;
  end process;
```

---

An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) : https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5p4s .

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity E is
  generic (
    my_generic_high_number : integer := 7;
    my_generic_low_number  : integer := 0
  );
end entity ;

architecture A of E is
  signal my_shift_reg : std_logic_vector(my_generic_high_number downto my_generic_low_number);
  signal clock : std_logic;
begin
  process (clock) is
    alias m is my_shift_reg;
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      my_shift_reg(m'high downto m'low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(m'high -1 downto m'low);
    end if;
  end process;

  process (clock) is
    alias index is my_shift_reg;
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      my_shift_reg(index'high downto index'low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(index'high -1 downto index'low);
    end if;
  end process;

  process (clock) is
    alias high is my_generic_high_number;
    alias low is my_generic_low_number;
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      my_shift_reg(high downto low + 1) <= my_shift_reg(high -1 downto low);
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture A;
```

Comment: I did think an alias may be a way of doing it, however, I'm more looking at it from `'high` referring to the shift_reg on that specific line, i.e. if I have more than 1 shift register I would have to write more and more aliases. I guess im more looking for something like this.... Line1 : `shift_reg1('high downto 'low + 1) <= shift_reg1('high -1 downto 'low);` Line2 : `shift_reg2('high downto 'low + 1) <= shift_reg2('high -1 downto 'low);` This means that shift_reg1 and 2 could be different lengths and it still works... Thank you for your suggestion though

Comment: I do like it where you make an alias of the shift register in the process statement, its a nice way to keep the namespace clear! Greate idea!

Comment: @dyslexicgruffalo Kind of like `end` in Matlab, if you happen to know that language: In Matlab, `my_array(2:end)` is short for `my_array(2:length(my_array))`.  Would be a great feature, but I think you're asking for an extra language feature, not something you can implement within the current language definition...